# VueJS doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-resource

I have a problem with running VueJS on mobile devices. I created a weather prediction app on copepen.io

Here is the link for the project:

http://codepen.io/techcater/pen/xOZmgv

HTML code:

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <h1>Your Local Weather</h1>
      <p>
        {{location}}
      </p>
      <p>
        {{temperature}}
        <a @click="changeDegree">{{degree}}</a>
      </p>
      <p>
        {{weather | capitalize}}
      </p>

      <img :src="iconURL" alt="" />
      <br>
      <a href="https://ca.linkedin.com/in/dalenguyenblogger" target="_blank">by Dale Nguyen</a>
<!--   <pre>{{$data | json}}</pre> -->
    </div>
```

JS code:

```
new Vue({
        el: '.container-fluid',

        data: {
          location: "",
          temperature: "",
          degree: "C",
          weather: "",
          iconURL: ""
        },

        created: function(){
          this.getWeather();
        },

        methods: {
          getWeather: function(){
            var that = this;

            this.$http.get("http://ipinfo.io").then((response) => {
                  console.log(response.data);
                  that.location = response.data.city + ", " + response.data.country;

                  // Get weather informaiton
                  var api = 'ebd4d312f85a230d5dc1db91e20c2ace';
                  var city = response.data.city;
                  var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={CITY}&APPID={APIKEY}&units=metric";
                  url = url.replace("{CITY}",city);
                  url = url.replace("{APIKEY}", api); 

                  that.$http.post(url,{dataType: 'jsonp'},{
              headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }}).then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data);
                  that.temperature = response.data.main.temp;
                  that.weather = response.data.weather[0]['description'];
                  that.iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + response.data.weather[0]['icon'] + ".png";
                  }, (response) => {
                      // error callback
                  });

              }, (response) => {
                  console.log(response.data);            
              });            
          },

          changeDegree: function() {
            if(this.degree == "C"){
              this.degree = "F";
              this.temperature = Math.round((this.temperature*9/5 + 32)*100)/100;
            }else {
              this.degree = "C";
              this.temperature = Math.round(((this.temperature - 32)*5 /9)* 100)/100;
            }
          }
        }
      })
```

It works well on my laptop but not on mobile. At first, I thought that it is because of Codepen. It may cause something when running through the site. However, when I created a project on my website, it also doesn't work.

Can you help to find the issue? Thanks,

Comment: Whats exactly failing in the mobile device?

Comment: What mobile device? Safari iOS, Android?

Comment: @YerkoPalma I use Iphone, and I tried on safari and chrome browser.

Comment: @gurghet I use Iphone, and I tried on safari and chrome browser.

Comment: FYI chrome browser *is* safari

Comment: @gurghet how can chrome browser is safari? They two separate apps on my Iphone. Does it work on your mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this. I works on my mobile now. I believe that I will work on other browses too. The problem is that some browsers doesn't recognize the operation ">", so I changed it.

Here is the new code:

```
getWeather: function(){
            var that = this;

            this.$http.get('http://ipinfo.io', {'headers': {
        'Origin': 'http://yourdomain.com'}
            }).then(function(response) {
                  console.log(response.data);
                  that.location = response.data.city + ", " + response.data.country;

                  // Get weather informaiton
                  var api = 'ebd4d312f85a230d5dc1db91e20c2ace';
                  var city = response.data.city;
                  var url = "https://crossorigin.me/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={CITY}&APPID={APIKEY}&units=metric";
                  url = url.replace("{CITY}",city);
                  url = url.replace("{APIKEY}", api); 

                  that.$http.post(url,{dataType: 'jsonp'},{
              headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
            }}).then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                  that.temperature = response.data.main.temp;
                  that.weather = response.data.weather[0]['description'];
                  that.iconURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + response.data.weather[0]['icon'] + ".png";
                  }).then(function(){
                      // error callback
                  });

              }).then(function(){
                  console.log(response.data);            
              });            
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be working well, except that on codepen it gives me error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ipinfo.io/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://s.codepen.io' is therefore not allowed access.`.

You can put your domain name on `headers` options to enable cross-origin, here is example:

```
this.$http.get('http://ipinfo.io', {
    'headers': {
        'Origin': 'http://yourdomain.com'
    }
})
```

See example: http://bozue.com/weather.html

I also noticed you put `vue.min.js` and `vue-resource.js` scripts in wrong order that might trigger some error, `vue.min.js` should be on the first place.

Comment: if I use crossorigin.me, it will show false location. Does it work on your mobile devices? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer. I didn't check it yet, but you can check http://bozue.com/weather.html on your mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for the headers. It works great! 
About the mobile site. I still doesn't work :(

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of you mobile browser? for me everything seems to be okay except that http://ipinfo.io sometimes failed to determine the city and region which causes some errors when requesting data from api.openweathermap.org. I'm using chrome on android.

Comment: Here is screenshot from my mobile device, https://www.diigo.com/item/image/5kg0i/7wm0?size=o

Comment: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNKWJDwHmMstXG2nF5A17gkzaJD-SA0Ex2OuamzYs3mDUycYvTTYa9OyVm6vtavng?key=SVdvRF9VQWpyOWN6SERjMXM4ZTlkMjQ4Um9GOHJR this is my screenshot.

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled on your device's browser?

Comment: Yes, I checked in settings and it turned on. I used Ajax before, and I was able to view it on my phone.

Comment: Make sure your phone & browser support VueJS, you can view the list here https://github.com/vuejs/vue