# <v-btn v-on:click.native="sendGroupMsg">Send Message</v-btn>, sendGroupMsg is defined in methods:{ }. works on laptop but not on phones

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mobile, vue-component

The button`<v-btn v-on:click.native="sendGroupMsg">Send Message</v-btn>` works as expected firing the `sendGroupMsg` from my `methods:{}`
but The button does not work on mobile devices. The click just does not do anything.

```
<div>
   <v-btn v-on:click.native="sendGroupMsg">Send Message</v-btn>
<div>
```

in my methods:{}

```
 methods: {
sendGroupMsg() {}
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what the problem is, because you didn't post any code, but these might help you: [vuejs doesn't work on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125480/vuejs-doesnt-work-on-mobile), [click not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400274/vuejs-click-doesnt-work-on-mobile-click-listener-is-not-detected)

Comment: added now, please check if this gives a better idea.

Comment: Are you using the same browser in laptop and mobile?

Comment: Yes I tried in Chrome and Safari in iOS @Still_learning I also tried removing the .native after click, no luck.

Comment: You tried Chrome on laptop and Safari on mobile?

Comment: No, I tried Chrome on laptop. and on Mobile I tried both Safari and Chrome

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207530/discussion-between-dholu-and-still-learning).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an element overlapping the button when on mobile? I've ran into that more than once.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter the v-btn is inside <div>, could that be the issue ?

Comment: Possibly, it's hard to say without actually debugging on a mobile device. It's usually really obvious when you start inspecting the elements in the web inspector and can visually see their dimensions.

Comment: Cool, gotta debug on a mobile device itself, Thank you anyways @DigitalDrifter

Comment: Chrome offers quite a few device profiles in the desktop browser, you could always start there also.

Comment: yes it works perfectly there without any errors, but when i run it on the phone connected on the network, The button just doesn't work.